# SOAPUI: Modify Request: Groovy: appendNode applicable arguments

Tags: groovy, request, soapui, xmlslurper

I'm trying to modify a SOAP Request by adding a duplicate child node with different value.

This is what I have so far:

Request:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xlmns:ns1 = "..." xlmns:ns2 = "..." xlmns:ns3 = "..." xlmns:ns4 = "...">
   <soapenv:Body>
       <ns2:OperationName>
          <ns3:CuteN>77777</ns3:CuteN>
          <ns3:RaveN>666</ns3:RaveN>
       </ns2:OperationName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Request to be modified as: (fill the xml tags & add another tag `<RaveN></RaveN>` with a value)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xlmns:ns1 = "..." xlmns:ns2 = "..." xlmns:ns3 = "..." xlmns:ns4 = "...">
   <soapenv:Body>
       <ns2:OperationName>
          <ns3:CuteN>77777</ns3:CuteN>
          <ns3:RaveN>666</ns3:RaveN>
          <ns3:RaveN>888</ns3:RaveN>
       </ns2:OperationName>
    </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Code used:

```
/* Groovy Utilities Declaration */
def groovyUtils = new ns4.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

/* Request Holder Setup */
def request      = context.expand('${RequestStepName#Request}')
def requestHolder    = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("request")

/* Declaring Namespaces */
requestHolder.namespaces["soapenv"] = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
requestHolder.namespaces["ns2"]     = "..."
requestHolder.namespaces["ns3"]     = "..."
requestHolder.namespaces["ns4"]     = "..."

/* Set few string names */
def soapEnvXString       = "//soapenv:Envelope"
def soapBodyXString      = "/soapenv:Body"
def operXString          = "/ns2:OperationName"
def raveNumXString       = "/ns3:RaveNum"

/* create object of Request nodes */
def parentNode       = requestHolder.getDomNode(soapEnvXString + soapBodyXString + operXString)

def reqRaveNumTwo = "888"

if(reqRaveNumTwo != null && reqRaveNumTwo != "")
{
    /* create new node */   
    def secondRaveNumNode = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText("""<ns3:RaveNum>${reqRaveNumTwo}</ns3:RaveNum>""")
    parentNode.appendNode(secondRaveNumNode)
}

/* Update the request holder properties */
requestHolder.updateProperty(true)
```

Error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj$ElementXobj.appendNode() is applicable for argument types: (groovy.util.slurpersupport.NodeChild) values: [888]
```

I know I'm missing something here, this is my 3rd day of Groovy deep-dive. Any help will be much appreciated, Thanks in advance!

Comment: This questions has been answered by @Albciff below. There were few changes that I made to the above code to get it to actually work. The updated code is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are two problems in your code, first you've to use `appendChild` method because you're trying to add a child inside your `<ns2:OperationName>` node (not `appendNode` method which not exist in your object), the second problem is that you're mixing the `XmlSlurper` classes with `XmlBeans`, due you can't add the "nodes" to an object from one engine to another.

You've to change the code inside your `if` statement to fit these corrections, so you can use something like:

```
if(reqRaveNumTwo != null && reqRaveNumTwo != "")
{
    /* create new node */   
    def nodeHolder  = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("<ns3:RaveNum xmlns:ns3=\"...\">${reqRaveNumTwo}</ns3:RaveNum>")
    def itemNode = nodeHolder.getDomNode( "//ns3:RaveNum" )
    // import the node
    def secondRaveNumNode = parentNode.getOwnerDocument().importNode(itemNode,false)
    // and finally append it
    parentNode.appendChild(secondRaveNumNode)
}
```

instead of:

```
if(reqRaveNumTwo != null && reqRaveNumTwo != "")
{
    /* create new node */   
    def secondRaveNumNode = new XmlSlurper(false,false).parseText("""<ns3:RaveNum>${reqRaveNumTwo}</ns3:RaveNum>""")
    parentNode.appendNode(secondRaveNumNode)
}
```

This code using `XmlBeans` to create the new node looks less intuitive however this way it works `:)`.

Additionally I saw this in your code: `def groovyUtils = new ns4.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)`, I suppose it's only a `typo` however it must be `def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)`

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you so very much for pointing me in the right direction! It makes sense now.

Comment: @ssc nice to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Code was updated as below to get it to actually work:

```
/* Groovy Utilities Declaration */
def groovyUtils = new ns4.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context)

/* Request Holder Setup */
def request      = context.expand('${RequestStepName#Request}')
def requestHolder    = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("request")

/* Declaring Namespaces */
requestHolder.namespaces["soapenv"] = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
requestHolder.namespaces["ns2"]     = "..."
requestHolder.namespaces["ns3"]     = "..."
requestHolder.namespaces["ns4"]     = "..."

/* Set few string names */
def operXString          = "//ns2:OperationName"
def raveNumXString       = "//ns3:RaveNum"

/* create object of Request nodes */
def parentNode = requestHolder.getDomNode(operXString)

def reqRaveNumTwo = "888"

if(reqRaveNumTwo != null && reqRaveNumTwo != "")
{
    /* create new node */   
    def nodeHolder  = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("<ns3:RaveNum xmlns:ns3=\"ns3\">${reqRaveNumTwo}</ns3:RaveNum>")
    def itemNode = nodeHolder.getDomNode(raveNumXString)
    // import the node
    def secondRaveNumNode = parentNode.getOwnerDocument().importNode(itemNode,false)
    // and finally append it
    parentNode.appendChild(secondRaveNumNode)
}

/* Update the request holder properties */
requestHolder.updateProperty(true)
context.requestContent = requestHolder.xml
```